# Xamarin Android CarouselView with IndicatorView position below the image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.carouselview

How can i put the indicatorview below and center of the image?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PJ6P.jpg

I tried position and other stuff but i can't seem to move the indicatorview below the image.

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <!--<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10"
                            Style="{StaticResource RetailHeaderImage}"
                            Source="{Binding ImageSource}">
                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>-->
                            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUrls}" IndicatorView="indicatorView" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" >
                                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            LoadingPlaceholder="loading.gif"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            BackgroundColor="Black"
                            Source="{Binding}">
                                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

                            </CarouselView>
                        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                           IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                           SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                           VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        
                        <Label Text="{Binding ReferenceSku.Name}" Style="{StaticResource RetailHeaderText}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                       
                    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: You are using a stacklayout with orientation horizontal. That tells xamarin to lay out elements left to right. If that isn’t what you want, then don’t tell xamarin that. Read StackLayout doc. Google for doc that talks about other layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Orientation` of the `StackLayout` to `Vertical`. And then set the `IndicatorView` in the center of the `StackLayout`.

Refer to the xaml below:

```
  <StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!--<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10"
                        Style="{StaticResource RetailHeaderImage}"
                        Source="{Binding ImageSource}">
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>-->
        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUrls}" IndicatorView="indicatorView" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" >
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}"></Image>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

        </CarouselView>
        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                       IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                       SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

        <Label Text="Name"    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Any update? Have you solved this issue?